# Modern tsconfig.json setup to support ES6 import / export module syntax when target is browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, require, tsc

TLDR I am targeting the browser. Using VSCode to write typescript and consume a (sample) npm package. I checked as best I can but I get an uncaught error in browser console saying

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Longer version:

I am trying to work in my typescript project with the a package named Graphemer, but I had a similar issue with another package so I think this is my issue, not the packages. I am writing my code in VScode, target is the browser. Here is my tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016", 
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,   
    "skipLibCheck": true   
  }
```

node -v gives version v16.17.0
tsc -v gives Version 4.9.3
Chrome browser is Version 111.0.5563.65 (Official Build) (64-bit)

So...

1. I install Graphemer into the project folder /node_modules folder via $ npm i graphemer.
2. The docs in Graphemer [github](https://github.com/flmnt/graphemer) say I can then, in my own TS file, do

```js
import Graphemer from 'graphemer';

const splitter = new Graphemer();
```

3. So I make a main.ts file containing

```
import Graphemer from "Graphemer";

function test() {
    const splitter = new Graphemer();
}
```

4. No errors in VSCode or TSC. I open the browser and look in the console and I see the error message:

```js
main.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at main.js:6:21
```

And I look in the /dist/main.js file to see

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const Graphemer_1 = __importDefault(require("Graphemer"));
function test() {
    const splitter = new Graphemer_1.default();
}
```

Where of course there is a line referencing require...

```
const Graphemer_1 = __importDefault(require("Graphemer"));
```

Question - what is the proper configuration of TSC, when targeting the browser, to get the JS generated to simply work with ES6 import/export module syntax?

Supplementary info:

The content of the Graphemer file /node_modules/Grapheme /lib/indexjs is

```js
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const Graphemer_1 = __importDefault(require("./Graphemer"));
exports.default = Graphemer_1.default;
console.log('exports',exports)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `npm` modules in a browser-hosted application, you'll need to use a bundler like Vite, Webpack, Rollup, Browserify, etc. That's because you won't provide the entire `node_modules` directory in `script` tags in your application. The purpose of the bundler in this situation is to wrap up your code *along with* code from `node_modules` and put it into "bundles" that you then include in your browser application.

Alternatively, you can use some `npm` modules directly via https://unpkg.com, and many of them may also be available with UMD builds (so they work in various environments, including browsers) on CDNs like https://cdnjs.com/ where you *can* directly reference them in your script tags.

Comment: Thanks for prompt and succinct answer. I am curious - I had previously written my first TypeScript project without using any node packages. I had used modules which I wrote, and used the ES6 export / import syntax. Am I right that because none of those modules mentioned require() I 'got away with it' in respect of the need for a packager?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat - Glad that helped! :-) It's not a matter of getting away with anything, it's that you only need a bundler if you need features the bundler provides. If you weren't using any `npm` modules, you didn't need a bundler to handle them. It's perfectly fine (and normal) not to use `npm` modules in your browser code, to instead use scripts directly from CDNs and such or just use your own code, in which case you didn't need a bundler. Looking at Graphemer, it doesn't look like they provide UMD builds, so you may need a bundler to use it unless you can fork and adapt it.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat - FWIW, I currently really like [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/). Just `npm install --save-dev vite` then add a build script to `"scripts"` in `"package.json"`: `vite build`. By default, it doesn't require any configuration -- it assumes your entry point is `index.html` and puts the bundled files in a `dist` subdirectory. And as the name suggests (if you speak French, which sadly I don't), it's *very* fast. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder - now using vite, and documented my journey in my self-answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[I am self-answering as a way of storing notes to myself and in case this helps anyone else]

Ok - I needed a bundler to make a project using ES6 import commands work with modules that are installed via "npm imstall moduleName", because these modules predominantly use the node.js form of modularity which uses the 'require' approach and not the ES6 'import' approach.

We are in a time of flux around module wiring at time of writing [March 2023]. The package builders who wrote those great packages we can just grab via npm followed appropriate standards and I guess it all works fine when preparing code to run on the server in node. For me, targeting the browser and coming to the concept of bundling for the first time, it was a bit of a confusion, particularly as I had written a projected using ES6 imports without an issue (it did not have any npm-sourced packages in that instance).

So what did I do to get this working? Followed TJ Crowder's advice.

It is worth saying that before TJ's answer came in I started looking at WebPack as this was what my research was leading me toward as the go-to bundler. However, I was seeing folks mentioning concerns about config complexity and performance. I also felt that I would be adding a ton of complexity to the tooling - before this it was me and VSCode - how would I ever get a workmate set up with the same environment? I value simplicity, stability, robustness and longevity highly in my dev environment, and my research was getting scary.

Don't get me wrong, I have used require.js in other previous projects, so I'm not an entire newbie, I just didn't like the feeling of the lunatics taking over the asylum.

I had come across Vite in my research and I decided on a spin of the wheel with it before I dived into WebPack.

Vite's quickstart page should be checked in case there are changes there, but effectively this is all I had to do to set up a new vite project:

1. Start VSCode and start a new terminal window - you **do not** need to create a folder first!
2. In the terminal window, cd to the folder that will be the *parent* folder of your project. Vite will create a project folder for you in the next step.
3. Now run

```
 npm create vite@latest
```

which will produce a sequence of prompts.

- project name : You will be asked the name of your project - whatever you type here becomes the name of the project folder AND the name of the project in the package.json file.
- Select a framework : this is a list of library types like vanilla JS, React and Vue - select a TypeScript project select Vanilla JS here.
- Select a variant : here you are asked whether your Vanilla JS project is Plain JS or TypeScript. Choose TypeScript.

It looks like this:

```
npm create vite@latest
Need to install the following packages:
  create-vite@4.1.0
Ok to proceed? (y) y
√ Project name: ... myProject
√ Package name: ... myProject
√ Select a framework: » Vanilla
√ Select a variant: » TypeScript

Scaffolding project in <path to parent folder>\myProject...
```

4. On completion, you are prompted with the following:

```
Done. Now run:

  cd myProject
  npm install  <<< when you run this it will read the package.json that vite set up to know what to install
  npm run dev  <<< when you run this it prepares and starts the template project.
```

Pay special attention to the cd - it's telling you to make the current folder the new project folder you just created. If you miss this then the following commands (reasonably) go wrong. So do not foget the cd!

The run dev command produces the following

```
npm run dev

> myProject@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v4.1.4  ready in 441 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help

h
  Shortcuts
  press r to restart the server
  press u to show server url
  press o to open in browser
  press c to clear console
  press q to quit
```

The immediately interesting shortcut here is the *o* which opens a browser tab on the vite dev server IP, showing the current template index.html page.

Looking at the project folder setup, we have

```
myProject (root folder)
├── node_modules
├── public
├── src
│   └── counter.ts
│   └── main.ts
│   └── style.css
│   └── typescript.svg
│   └── vite-env.d.ts
└── index.html
└── package.json
└── package-lock.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Vite uses index.html as the start point for its packaging / bundling process. Other bundlers put it away in a subfolder, but vite keeps it in the root.

You can now open the myProject folder in VSCode and see and interact with the files, meaning you can start developing, add modules in the src folder, etc.

At this point it should be noted that no config files were edited to get to this stage. No weird error messages appeared in the terminal window. No two-steps-forward-one-step-back or snakes-and-ladders issues.

**So what of interaction with the sample npm package Graphemer ?**

Oh yes! My origial question - also good news. I opened a VSCode terminal window and ran

```
$ npm i graphemer
```

Which installed Graphemer. I then modified index.html to include a new para with id of 'info' and modified the /src/main.ts to include:

```
import Graphemer from 'graphemer';

const splitter = new Graphemer();
// split the string to an array of grapheme clusters (one string each)
const string = `Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn ☃ `;
const graphemes = splitter.splitGraphemes(string);

...current contents of main.ts

document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#info')!.innerHTML = 'Unicode string is [' + graphemes +']';
```

Which produced the following - notice the yellow highlit line showing the expected output. [Aside: [Graphemer](https://github.com/flmnt/graphemer) is used to handle multi-character Unicode such as is required by many emojis and languages] The Vite & TS images etc are all part of the standard Vite template. The counter is clickable and increments at each click thus confirming early that the TS transpiling works.

[image: Sample index.html output with Graphemer]

Again it should be noted that this all just worked out of the box.

**So what about building for production?**

Execute the command

```
npm run build

> test-vite-project@0.0.0 build
> tsc && vite build

vite v4.1.4 building for production...
✓ 21 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                       0.45 kB
dist/assets/typescript-f6ead1af.svg   1.44 kB
dist/assets/index-3443e464.css        1.24 kB │ gzip:  0.64 kB
dist/assets/index-366ad949.js        96.25 kB │ gzip: 16.48 kB
PS myProject>
```

Which produces a /dist folder containing the index.html file and an /assets sub-folder containing the a file of bundled JS and another of bundled CSS.

**Conclusion**

It appears that Vite is viable for my use-case. So far it seems to be simple to work with, at least in this uncomplicated case, avoids configuration distractions, achieves the requirement of enabling npm packages with ES6 module syntax, and just plain works.

From reading at the [Vite website](https://vitejs.dev/) I know that Vite uses [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) under the covers and it remains to be seen what the limitations or extra config hassles are. However at this stage I am happy with Vite as a bundler.